# How to pass object in ViewBag which is to be used in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I am passing few values in ViewBag to my View which then has some jquery written to read and use it.

```
public ActionResult Update(int id)
{
    ViewBag.ProductId = id;
    var settings = _service.GetAdvancedSettings();
    ViewBag.Settings = settings;
    return View();
}
```

Just to give you an idea I have posted My `Setting` class which is returned from the `GetSettings()` method.

```
public class AdvancedSettings 
{
    public bool ShowName { get; set; }
    public bool ShowQuantity { get; set; }
    public bool ShowPrice { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting the following error.

[image]

I was able to read and use the int value of the "id" till now. How do I use the object and it values ?

Comment: I don't think it is good practice to mix, razor code in JavaScript code

Comment: Have you tried to use `'<%# Service.Models.... %>'` ? But I'd recommend you to use `hiddenfield` as an example and put the value of `AdvancedSettings` in codebehind to `hiddenfield` and in your `JavaScript` get the value from `hiddenfield`

Comment: @Yasser - Do you want viewbag value to be access in script file

Answer (score 4):

You can convert settings to json:

```
var settings = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Settings)));
```

In this situation you should to create view model class that represents settings to avoid errors in the future if settings will be changed and can't be convertable to json.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden input inside your view :

```
    <input type="hidden" id="AdvancedSettings_ShowName" value="@ViewBag.Settings.ShowName" />
    <input type="hidden" id="AdvancedSettings_ShowQuantity" value="@ViewBag.Settings.ShowQuantity" />
    <input type="hidden" id="AdvancedSettings_ShowPrice" value="@ViewBag.Settings.ShowPrice" />
```

Then call the values of those hidden inputs inside your js file :

```
var settings = {
    showName : $('#AdvancedSettings_ShowName').val(),
    ShowQuantity: $('#AdvancedSettings_ShowQuantity').val(),
    ShowPrice: $('#AdvancedSettings_ShowPrice').val()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a Viewbag object in controller. Create a script var in View. Now that var you can use in your js file. Hete GetContainersUrl is of string having json value.

```
<script>
    var SELECTED_BLOBS = "@ViewBag.GetContainersUrl";
</script>
```

in js file use like this

```
if (SELECTED_BLOBS != "") {
        var obj = JSON.parse(SELECTED_BLOBS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing the value as model and then encoding it using `System.Web.Helpers.Json` worked. Here's a snippet of the code I used.

Controller

```
public ActionResult Update(int id)
{
    ViewBag.ProductId = id;
    var settings = _service.GetAdvancedSettings();
    ViewBag.Settings = settings;
    return View(settings);
}
```

View

```
@model AdvancedSettings

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       var jsonSettings = "@System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(Model)";
       var settings = JSON.parse(jsonSettings.replace( /&(lt|gt|quot);/g , '"'));

       console.log(settings);
    });
</script>
}
```